# Why does powermail send an email despite recognizing spam

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x, powermail

We wanted to activate spam protection in EXT:powermail and implemented the example configuration from the documentation.

First we switched on the honeypot and the session check and the mails to us (administrators). After a few minutes we received some emails.

At first we thought it was just a transition, but unfortunately it didn't stay that way. We even contacted a website user by phone to see if he noticed anything when submitting the form (session check failed). But he hadn't noticed anything out of the ordinary. He also received a confirmation email and our recipient received the completed form.

Now our question: is it normal that the mails are sent despite a negative session check or honeypot (sometimes both together), or do we still have a configuration error? Why is an email sent at all if the form was detected as spam?

We use:

- TYPO3 10.4.23
- Powermail 8.2.3

Comment: Powermail runs multiple checks and creates for every submission a Spam-Indication-Number. Maybe the number was below 75%? Found this documentation: https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/SpamPrevention.md

Answer (score 0):

Powermail will not send mails to the sender if the spam check is failing. There are a few checks which then lead to an spam-indication (from 0 to 100%). You can configure which check has which indication and when will be a stop in sending normal mails.
I would turn on logs or notification emails on spam for admins via TypoScript setup - see documentation https://github.com/einpraegsam/powermail/blob/develop/Documentation/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/SpamPrevention.md#configuration-via-typoscript